# Como eu devo preencher as meta tags?

Tags: html, seo, html-meta-tag

Consegui achar formas de preencher outras meta tags mas estas, eu não faço a menor ideia. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

```
<meta content='xxxxx' name='alexaVerifyID'/>
<meta content='xxxxx' name='yandex-verification'/>
<meta content='India' name='geo.placename'/>
<meta content='xxxxx' name='Author'/>
<meta content='general' name='rating'/>
<meta content='id' name='geo.country'/>
```

Acho que devo colocar a descrição aqui, certo?

```
<meta content='xxxxx' property='og:description'/>
```

Aqui eu não sei se deixo assim já que está preenchido ou se devo colocar siglas do Brasil.

```
<meta content='en_US' property='og:locale'/> 
<meta content='en_GB' property='og:locale:alternate'/>
<meta content='id_ID' property='og:locale:alternate'/>
```

Comment: uma sugestão que pode responder sua pergunta: pega um site famoso de portal, tipo UOL ou G1 e veja no código fonte `view-source:www.uol.com.br` como eles fazem. Mas estude cada tipo antes, para não colocar informação desnecessária.

Comment: [Aqui tem mais informações](http://tableless.com.br/utilizando-meta-tags-facebook/)